# Gradle DSL method not found: 'StopExecutionException()'

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying add "thow StopExecutionException" in my android gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
task exportJar(type: Copy) {

    def classesJar = file("build/intermediatess/bundles/release/classes.jar")
    if (classesJar.exists()) {
       //some code
    } else {
        **throw StopExecutionException**(classesJar.getPath() + " doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

I use existing solution:

[Recommended way to stop a Gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312259/recommended-way-to-stop-a-build-with-gradle)

but gradle doesn't recoginze StopExecutionException and any other Exception.

What I have to do? Apply some kind of plugin? Add classpath dependancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgot to add a `new` before the exception. You need to throw it like a usual java exception:

```
throw new StopExecutionException(classesJar.getPath() + " doesn't exist");
```