# groovy/gradle plugin faile build conditionally

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I am writing a gradle custom plugin and the requirement is to fail build conditionally based on a parameter.

To fail the build i am throwing GradleException. If the property is not set, i want to log the reason and stop executing the plugin. Is there anyway other than System.exit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to stop a Gradle build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312259/recommended-way-to-stop-a-gradle-build)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312259/recommended-way-to-stop-a-gradle-build

Answer (score 0):

I ended up throwing StopActionException when i need to stop action without failing the build.