# Intellij Gradle Plugin error when task throw exception

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I create Gradle task which requires additional property (`./gradlew myTask -PmyProperty=something`), so I want to check if this property exists and stop build task if not.

```
if (!project.hasProperty("myProperty")) {
    throw new StopActionException("Please blebleble...")
}
```

And it works properly if I use gradlew, but Intellij suggests to import changes (Intellij Gradle plugin) and then I get an error exactly in this line where I throw exception. It seems like plugin tries run this tasks before I launch them or something. Is there any possibility to fix it?

I did it exactly like here: [Recommended way to stop a Gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312259/recommended-way-to-stop-a-gradle-build)

Comment: Why you need to stop build? If you need some external values for building - add them in `gradle.properties` as empty. android studio is trying to build app when you press `sync`.

Comment: Ok, it works, but it's not exactly what I need. When I set default property value in gradle.properties, when user calls my task from the command line without  -PmyProperty=something this default value will be taken. But an exception should be thrown. I need to stop build, because my task should have configName passed as a parameter (if no parameter passed it should stop).