# Recommended way to stop a Gradle build from an artifact transfrom

Tags: gradle, build

How can I stop a gradle build from within an artifact transform?

Any exceptions I throw are completely swallowed by gradle and the build continues on as normal until it hits a `FileNotFoundException` as I haven't provided an output jar.

None of the solutions provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312259/recommended-way-to-stop-a-gradle-build) work.

I would like to provide some additional information in my error messages, rather than the build fail for an unknown reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artifact transforms properly fail the build in any gradle task, but from within `ideaSyncTask` they do not fail the build.

This is an IntelliJ bug, see [this IDEA issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-312545/Exceptions-thrown-in-an-artifact-transform-do-not-fail-ideaSyncTask)